# How to make jszip generate same buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, zip

Here is code

```
import JSZip = require('jszip');
import crypto = require('crypto');

let zip = new JSZip();

zip.file("hello.txt", "Hello World\n");
zip.folder("nested").file("hello.txt", "Hello World\n");

zip.generateAsync({
    type: 'nodebuffer',
    mimeType: 'application/epub+zip',
    compression: 'DEFLATE',
    compressionOptions: {
        level: 9
    },
})
    .then(buf => {
        const md5 = crypto.createHash('md5');
        let result = md5.update(buf).digest('hex');

        console.dir(result);
    })
;
```

If run this code 2 time, will get diff md5

How can i make it is same buffer when context is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the .zip archive entries created by JSZip will have file modification timestamps associated with them. This results in small differences (a couple of bytes usually) between files generated at different times. So we need to specify the file timestamps manually as well as ensuring we create only *virtual* folders in the .zip archive.

This approach should work for you (giving the same MD5 hash each time):

```
import JSZip = require('jszip');
import crypto = require('crypto');

// You must fix the date (set to the same value) so that the zip archive timestamps will be equal.
// Also we must create virtual folders or they will be assigned timestamps too, resulting in a different hash.
const options = { date: new Date('2019-07-24 06:00:00Z'), createFolders: false};
zip.file("hello.txt", "Hello World\n", options);
zip.file("nested/hello.txt", "Hello World\n", options);

zip.generateAsync({
    type: 'nodebuffer',
    mimeType: 'application/epub+zip',
    compression: 'DEFLATE',
    compressionOptions: {
        level: 9
    },
})
    .then(buf => {
        const md5 = crypto.createHash('md5');
        let result = md5.update(buf).digest('hex');
        console.dir(result);
    })
;
```

Comment: looks like can't use `zip.folder("nested").file("hello.txt", "Hello World\n", options);` if use `zip.folder("nested")` , md5 will still change

Comment: Yes, because it will create a folder in the zip directory with the timestamp, which will change the md5. You might be able to set the timestamp of the folder, but I don't think so. If you use zip.file("nested/hello.txt", "Hello World\n", options);, it should give the same result!

Comment: i make a pr https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/pull/610 and a helper function for this https://github.com/bluelovers/ws-epub/blob/master/packages/jszip-fixed-date/index.ts